# Xuggler and playing from live stream

Tags: java, video, stream, xuggler

We're currently busy with a project in which we are trying to play a video file in a window from a live stream in Java. We've already managed to capture the stream via a Socket object using an InputStreamReader.

The next step is using an existing library (Xuggler) or code to decode this stream and display the contents (video) in a simple window.

The stream originates from the Parrot AR Drone 2.0 via IP address 192.168.1.1:5555.
That's where we got stuck. The code we're trying to use is the DecodeandPlayVideo example found here:

https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayVideo.java

Now it should be possible to use this with an inputstream but it should of course be in the right format. Is there some way you can help us do this?

Comment: Have you tried vlcj? Its very well documented and worked fine for me. I was consdering xaggler as well but after few days of evaluation vlcj came up on top of my list.

Comment: Today we have tried vlcj. So far no success. We want to display and manipulate the video from de Parrat Ar Drone 2.0. We think that Xuggle would be nice for both. Have anyone an example of how you can read from a http stream with Xuggle?

Comment: What do you mean by manipulate? Editing or navigating?

Comment: I mean navigation. We want to catch an object and follow that automatic with the drone.

Comment: @michel3vb Please do not edit the answer into the question. It you solved your particular problem you can click the button `Answer your Question` below the post. You will have to wait 48 hours(I think) but can then come back and mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark. I would encourage to expand what your edit in the answer though, as it is still not clear what you did to fix the problem. Adding a code sample usually helps clear that up.

Answer (score 3):

Oke we solved the problem:

First we make a TCP connection to the drone:

```
try
    {
        socket_video_tcp = new Socket();
        socket_video_tcp.connect(new InetSocketAddress(commandSender.droneInetAddress, commandSender.VIDEO_PORT));
    }
```

Our class is Runnable what means that we also have a method run()
In this method we send a video_enable command and we also disable the dynamic video bitrate by sending this command: video:bitrate_ctrl_mode 0;

```
public void run()
{
    commandSender.sendConfigCommand("VIDEO_ENABLE");
    commandSender.sendConfigCommand("VIDEOBITRATE");

    decode();
}
```

Our decode() method can be found here: https://github.com/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/blob/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayVideo.java

In this decode method we have changed this:

```
 if (container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
```

To this:

```
if (container.open(socket_video_tcp.getInputStream(), null) < 0)
```

That's all!!

Answer (score 0):

Copied from Edit in question:

> Today we solved this problem. We tried before to load the socket
>   connection into the Icontainer.open with
>   socketconnection.getInputStream . The result was 0 streams. After some
>   small adjustments the result is 1 stream and we can see the live video
>   from the drone on screen!

Comment: @michel3vb After you post your own answer, I will delete this one.