# How to put FFmpeg ffplay frame into my own Java application?

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, ar.drone

I am getting live video feedback from Parrot AR.Drone 2.0. I am able to get the incoming video streams from drone(using command-ffplay tcp://192.168.1.1:5555) and successfully output the live video for me. I notice that ffplay will display its own frame along with the live video.

So, is that possible to "direct" or put the frame into our own Java frame in application? How could I achieve that if I wish to implement that function in my own JCheckBox? E.G. If I click JCheckBox, it should automatically get live video streams from drone and display for me in application instead of using ffplay frame?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I just found it so I decided to write a possible solution for other users.

There are to ways to solve this one wrapping yourself the FFmpeg CLI for Java or using a wrapped FFmpeg library. The former will take a quite time and effort to make it. While the latter will be more practical to use.

For example, a nice library is [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv). You just need to add the maven repository to your project using the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
  <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can create a `SimplePlayer` class and use the `FFmpegFrameGrabber` class to decode a frame that is converted into an image and displayed in your Java app.

```
public class SimplePlayer
{
    private static volatile Thread playThread;
    private AnimationTimer timer;

    private int counter;

    public SimplePlayer(String source, GrabberListener grabberListener)
    {
        if (grabberListener == null) return;
        if (source.isEmpty()) return;

        counter = 0;

        playThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(source);
                grabber.start();

                grabberListener.onMediaGrabbed(grabber.getImageWidth(), grabber.getImageHeight());


                Java2DFrameConverter converter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    Frame frame = grabber.grab();
                    if (frame == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (frame.image != null) {
                        Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(converter.convert(frame), null);
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            grabberListener.onImageProcessed(image);
                        });
                    }
                grabber.stop();
                grabber.release();
                Platform.exit();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
        playThread.start();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        playThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

You can find the full implementation in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/teocci/Streaming-Player-Java).

Answer (score -1):

You need to decode the almost-but-not-quite H264 video format that the AR.Drone uses.  To do that, you need to do two things:

1. Handle the AR.Drone's custom video framing, which uses headers in their PaVE format. The format is documented in section 7.3 of the [AR.Drone Developer Guide](http://www.msh-tools.com/ardrone/ARDrone_Developer_Guide.pdf), but almost any of the existing AR.Drone libraries have code to handle PaVE headers.
2. Decode the H264 video frames that remain.  [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) wraps native libraries with Java, and is probably the best, fastest way to decode H264.  An alternative is the [h264j](https://code.google.com/p/h264j/) library, which is pure Java, but is slower and has some decoding glitches.

For more info, see these related questions:

[Xuggler and playing from live stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643648/xuggler-and-playing-from-live-stream)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307003/use-a-xuggler-videostream-in-javacv